# How to add bootstrap grid layout to search.php

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, search, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have the layout of my posts on my search results be 2 posts per line.  Right now there is 1 post, so I am trying to add in 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' to my search.php file.  However, every time I try to add it in nothing changes.  Does anyone have any solutions?

search.php

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <div id="page">

  <div class="column span-9 first" id="maincontent">

   <div class="content">

 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form-search form-inline-search" action="">
            <div class="input-group-search">
                <input type="search" value="" name="s" class="input-sm-search search-field-search form-control-search" placeholder="<?php echo $s ?>">
            </div>
        </form>
  
  <div class="clear"></div>

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <div class="search-post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'medium-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?>
    <div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
    </div>
 
   </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php else : ?>

  <h2 class="center">No posts found. Try a different search?</h2>
  <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/searchform.php'); ?>

 <?php endif; ?>

  </div> <!-- /content -->
 </div> <!-- /maincontent-->

 </div> <!-- /page -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is another version of a search.php I have been playing around with.  However, with this one the web page doesn't show up.

```html
<?php 

get_header(); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( [ 
'posts_per_page' => 15, 
'paged' => get_query_var('paged', 1) 
] ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?> 
<div id="ajax"> 
<?php 
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { $the_query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="row"> 
<article <?php post_class( 'col-sm-6 col-md-6' ); ?>> 
<div class="large-front-container"> 
<?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'large-front-thumbnail')); ?> 
</div> 
<div class="front-page-date"><?php echo str_replace('mins', 'minutes', human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'); ?></div>
<h2><a class="front-page-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2> 
<p class="front-page-post-excerpt"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p> 
<div class="front-page-post-info"> 
<a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a> 
<?php get_template_part( 'front-shop-the-post' ); ?> 
<?php get_template_part( 'share-buttons' ); ?> 
<div class="front-comments"><?php comments_popup_link ('0', '1', '%', 'comment-count', 'none'); ?></div> 
</div> 
</article> 
</div> 


<?php if(get_query_var('paged') < $the_query->max_num_pages) { 
} 
} 
elseif (!get_query_var('paged') || get_query_var('paged') == '1') { 
echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>'; 
} 
wp_reset_postdata(); 
get_footer();
```

Comment: I believe you should replace `<div class="search-post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">` with `<div class="search-post col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">` but to provide a better answer, please share the link where it's live.

Comment: You would also need to wrap the entire search result in a `.container-fluid` and all the subsequent `.col-*-*` inside a `.row`.  Have you done that?

Comment: @RobertC No I haven't done that.  If you could help me with that I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @user6738171 Check out Bootstrap's guide for their Grid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  The structure recommendations I made are based on basic Bootstrap Grid layout.